# Kendo vue switch not showing up as shown in the documentation?

Tags: vue.js, kendo-ui

I installed the @progress/kendo-inputs-vue-wrapper npm package and imported the InputsInstaller as detailed [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/inputs/#toc-installation). However, when I use the `kendo-switch` tag in a form file, all I see is a circle, which can be filled for yes or unfilled for no.

```
<kendo-switch
    class="form-control"
    v-model="info.open"
    :messages-checked="'Yes'"
    :messages-unchecked="'No'" />
```

[image: What I see][image: What I should see]

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your template is loading these 2 css files to get the same result.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="...../bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="...../all.css" />
```

here is the sample working
https://stackblitz.com/edit/wnlxcq?embed=1&file=index.html